Connecting to on-premises machine from VPN
I have a Linux host on-premises, and a VPN configured in AWS. I want to SSH securely to the Linux host
The host is behind a router. There is a static IP for router and static private IP for host.
I want that user can only SSH when they are connected to VPN.

Connect the Linux host to that VPN and have it pass client-to-client connections.
This depends on the VPN used; for example, use client-to-client for OpenVPN.
